# How to Deploy Owin Self Hosted Application In Production?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, owin, self-hosting

I have an Asp.Net Owin Self Hosted WebApi application.
The application can be installed as a windows service in production environment.

Currently I'm running and accessing the service via url http://localhost:8000 successfully.

Now I want to map the service to a domain to access it from public network. I have a registered domain and have control over it.
Ex: www.myservice.com

How can I point the domain to WebApi service for a Self Hosted Application?

Comment: Do you want to host your application on-premises?

Comment: Or you are going to host that inside a VM somewhere on Cloud?

Comment: @AdnanUmer I need to host it in a Windows VM. (In the same VM i'm hosting some other web application through IIS)

Comment: IIS will be already using 80 port. Do you want to host that on the different port? may be on 8000?

Comment: I have no restrictions on port number. I can use ports such as 8000.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to allow public access to your Self-hosted OWIN Web API app. Follow following Steps:

1. **Allow Inbound Connections from Firewall**

   Run `wf.msc` command to open up Windows Firewall with Advanced Security and add a new Inbound Rule for TCP port 8000 or the port you want to use.

   You can make sure your service is getting request by opening `<machine public ip>:8000` from other machines.
2. **Get Static IP from ISP**

   Request your ISP for static IP. Most of the times ISP charges extra for that. If you already have static IP, skip this step and move to next step.
3. **Point your domain to static IP**

   Lastly, go to your domain `DNS Manager` and add an `A Record` with `Host Name = www` and `IP Adress = <your machine static IP>`.

   You might also need to add another `A Record` with `Host Name = @` and `IP Adress = <your machine static IP>` if you want also want to access your service without `www`.

   > The procedure of adding A Record varies. You can simply read knowledge base documents provided by your registered on how to add `A Record`.