# How to deploy Owin Self Hosted Signalr Service to production

Tags: c#, windows-services, signalr, topshelf

I am trying to publish Owin Self Hosted Signalr Service(using TopShelf) to production server but it doesn't seem that clients can connect to the server after it's published. The settings and codes are pretty much the same as what you can find in the internet.

**Startup.cs**

```
app.Map("/service", map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableJSONP = true,
            EnableDetailedErrors = true
        };
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
}
```

**ServiceClass.cs (Server)**

```
 public bool StartService(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        //const string hostingUrl = "http://localhost:9000/";
        const string hostingUrl = "http://production-server:9000/"; 
        SignalR = WebApp.Start<Startup>(hostingUrl);
    }
```

**Default.html (Client)**

```
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/service.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="http://localhost:9000/service/hubs"></script>-->
    <script src="http://production-server:9000/service/hubs"></script>
</head>
```

**service.js (Client)**

```
//$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:9000/service";
$.connection.hub.url = "http://production-server:9000/service"; 

// Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
var sample = $.connection.service;
$.connection.hub.logging = true;  
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
    }).fail(function () { console.log('Cannot Connect!'); });;
});
```

**I have tried to**

1. make both server and client use localhost url -> code above Works
2. make both server and client use production url -> not working
3. make server code use localhost and client use production url -> not working
4. Allow port 9000 in firewall setting as answered here
   [How to Deploy Owin Self Hosted Application In Production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271665/how-to-deploy-owin-self-hosted-application-in-production?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

**Error Message in Chrome console**

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT